# How to get text of help tag in RUBY Capybara.Fail get the text help tag(Default value is 180 days and allowed value range is 30-180)any one help me

Tags: ruby, capybara

```
<label for='zip'>Password Duration – maximum days:</label>
<input Value="180" id="PasswordExpiryDays" name="PasswordExpiryDays" type="text"/>
<a class="links" id="PasswordAge_Tip" tabindex="-1" 
   onblur="HideLayer('PasswordAge')" 
   onmouseover="ShowLayer('PasswordAge')" 
   onmouseout="HideLayer('PasswordAge')" href="#">?</a>
<span id="PasswordAge" style="VISIBILITY: hidden;">     
    <table>
        <tr>      
           <td>
               Default value is 180 days and allowed value range is 30-180
           </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</span>
```

Fail get the text help tag value (Default value is 180 days and allowed value range is 30-180)any one help me.

Comment: i have tried with below but fail:                                                                                         span = page.find(:xpath,"//input[@id = 'PasswordAge']/table/tr/td")
value = span.text

Comment: Please format that html correctly.

Comment: Please post what you have tried because right now all you have is an HTML snippet but nothing showing the code that was used to parse this page.

Answer (score 0):

That element has visibility set to 'hidden'. Did you configured capybara to work on hidden elements?

Answer (score 0):

Reformatting your html so it's readable would help, and the id in the xpath that is failing is for a span in your html not for an input

```
span = page.find(:xpath,"//span[@id='PasswordAge']/table/tr/td", visible: false) # page.find('#PasswordAge td', visible: false) would be easier to read
value = span.text(:all)  # The all is necessary to get non-visible text
```

Comment: i have used it as below, but its throwing an error "Unable to find xpath "//span[@id = 'PasswordAge']/table/tr/td")"                                                                                                         code added : span = page.find(:xpath,"//span[@id = 'PasswordAge']/table/tr/td", visible: false) 
value = span.text(:all)

Comment: That error is telling you that the matching element isn't on the page - so either your example html above isn't the same as the page you're attempting to run against - or the content isn't on the page. Maybe that content is being generated by JS and you're running with a non-JS capable Capybara driver?

Comment: hmmm -- the more I think about it -- table elements aren't allowed in span elements for valid html -- so it may just be that your html isn't valid, especially if you're using the default rack-test driver

Comment: I have used following code & its working fine: " click_link('PasswordAge_Tip')
      sleep 3
      value = find(:id,'PasswordAge').text
      log "Help tag value is #{value}""   Thank you